# Prescient story about proto-hipsters

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books

I remember a short story which at the time (late eighties is when I read it) seemed most absurd, but which in a few decades has become prescient: a world where people in the old generation were complacent overconsuming hippies, while the new generation were concerned about the environment and blamed their elders for that.

Furthermore, I remember that the young folk wore lumberjack shirts and beards, and glorified life in the forests, making them eerily familiar. Add some thick glasses and a love for coffee-houses and the writer would have nailed present-day hipsters. Oh, and the irony; these future guys were dead serious about everything.

The story was in some kind of anthology. I may misremember some details. Anyone knows what I am talking about?

Comment: So this guy wrote about hipsters...before it was cool?  He was a hipster hipster?

Comment: Sounds like garden variety [Grunge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunge#Clothing) to me: "Clothing commonly worn by grunge musicians in Washington consisted of thrift store items and the typical outdoor clothing (most notably flannel shirts) of the region, as well as a generally unkempt appearance and long hair. Seattle and Aberdeen, Washington were logging towns and hence, the lumberjack attire was a common sight in the thrift stores for the low prices that musicians could afford."